# Bash syntax to upload subfolders via a cpanel.yml (other than the wildcard)

Tags: html, bash, git, yaml, cpanel

I've been following documentation at https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-deployment/

My issue is that my subfolders don't get copied unless I cheat.

The only way I can get my desired result is by using the command:

```
    - /bin/cp -r * $DEPLOYPATH
```

The problem with that is that is copies things you don't want copied

Here is the code that is failing me:

```
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/X/Y.com/
    - /bin/cp formEmailer.php $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp landing.html $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp portfolio.html $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp thank-you.html $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp style.css $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp -r /home/X/wbs/images $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp -r /home/X/wbs/assets $DEPLOYPATH
```

The last two lines aren't working for me. I've also tried them like this:

```
- /bin/cp -r images $DEPLOYPATH
- /bin/cp -r assets $DEPLOYPATH
```

Could anyone suggest the correct syntax to have my subfolders of images and assets other than just wildcarded the whole root folder?

The layout of the files is a root folder with the html and css files, and then there exists two subfolders(images, assets). Assets also has subfolders. images just has images and no additional subfolders.

Comment: Is that recursive? Try with `-R`

Comment: swapping -r with -R had no effect :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I'm copying all files in the public folder from my project's root directory to public_html.

```
deployment:
 tasks:
 - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/username/public_html
 - /bin/cp -r public/. $DEPLOYPATH
```

The alternative, like you tried, is to copy the entire public folder itself to public_html by using the following commands:

```
deployment:
 tasks:
 - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/username/public_html
 - /bin/cp -r public $DEPLOYPATH
```

Comment: For those not paying attention, a trailing / on a foldername changes the subject being copied, from the contents of the folder, to the folder itself.  I always confuse with/without the trailing slash, hence having a dry-run option is your friend, but basically Murray OB is right